# Get Last Order ID and Date Per Customer in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

It's an orcale database and I'm trying to get the last order ID and its date for each customer. I'm familiar enough with MySQL to be able to write something like the following in a MySQL system:

https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(OrderID), MAX(OrderDate) as Last_Order_Date,
    (SELECT OrderID FROM Orders O2 
    WHERE O2.CustomerId = O1.CustomerId
    ORDER BY OrderDate DESC LIMIT 1)
    AS LAST_ORDER_ID
FROM [Orders] O1
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerID
```

However I haven't been able to write the equivalent for an Oracle database. The part that trips me up is I have to write a subquery for the order by, then pick the top 1... but that also need to go into my bigger query of getting the last order for each customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MAX( ... ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ... )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm):

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       COUNT( OrderID ),
       MAX( OrderDate ) AS Last_Order_Date,
       MAX( OrderID ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY OrderDate ) AS Last_Order_ID
FROM   Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerID;
```

or use analytic functions:

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       Num_Orders,
       OrderDate AS Last_Order_Date,
       OrderID AS Last_Order_ID
FROM   (
  SELECT o.*,
         COUNT( OrderID ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerID ) AS Num_Orders,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerID
                             ORDER BY OrderDate DESC, OrderID DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   orders o
)
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER BY CustomerID;
```